# Where can I find answers to these Retargeting errors?

Tags: animation, makehuman

[image: Error Report]

With models imported from both MakeHuman and iClone7, and with bvh files from any source, I get the errors listed in the attached png file. I am not a programmer (or that bright, just a hobbyist), so I don't know where to begin in order to resolve this.

Thank You in advance for any insights/suggestions.

Kevin K

Comment: Looks like a bug in the script, should probably be reported to the authors

Comment: I think you probably have not clicked the the armature you want to animate. Can you share the file?